# Can I reply to moderator's question edit?

Tags: support, moderators, editing

I've seen that a moderator edited my question and I wanted to know if it is possible to leave a reply. I've seen I can edit the question again, but I think this could end up in the moderator editing it back again.

In this concrete case, I only wanted to know about the deletion of a tag that could catch the attention of potential good answers.

Comment: You can add a comment on the question or ask here in meta.   I assume that in relation to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/92076/revisions

Comment: I can see why [Tag:rich-snippets] was removed, you weren't asking about how this would effect your display in the search results.   I doubt that search engines pay attention to the schema you are asking about at all.   Microdata looks like it could be appropriate to me.

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can notify any editor of your question by leaving a comment with @ followed by their user name. For example, @StephenOstermiller or simply @Stephen  would work.

The name does not necessarily auto-complete the way it does when you reply to other comments, but the notification will go through. For details, see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

Comment: Nice.   I didn't know the @ replies could notify people that had edited a post.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

About [the specific edit](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/92076/revisions) you seem to ask about:

While a moderator also edited your question, the edit that removed tags came from me (I’m not a mod).

**Why I removed the [microdata](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microdata) tag:** Microdata is just a syntax, while Schema.org can be used with various syntaxes (commonly JSON-LD. Microdata, and RDFa). Your question doesn’t seem to be about how to use Microdata (i.e., the attributes `itemscope`, `itemprop` etc. in HTML5), but about how to use the vocabulary Schema.org (i.e., which types to use, like `VideoGame` etc.). Or in other words: Neither does answering this question require that someone knows Microdata, nor is it likely that someone could learn something about Microdata when visiting this question.

**Why I removed the [rich-snippets](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rich-snippets) tag:** Your question doesn’t seem to be about a Rich Snippet or how to get one. Just like in the case with Microdata, someone doesn’t need to know anything about Rich Snippets to answer your question nor are answers likely to be about this topic (as you didn’t ask about it). However, if you *do* want to know something about Rich Snippets in this context¹, I think you should ideally state this in the question, and in that case adding the [rich-snippets](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rich-snippets) tag is of course appropriate.

¹ note that Google’s [Software Apps Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/sw-app) does not seem to be available to every site, currently

Comment: Thanks for your answer Unor. I will ask more accurately next time!